# Query mongodb using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I need to query MongoDB and I am using Morphia to do that. I need to do something like this

```
 select * from table_name where (column_1== null or column_1== value1) AND (column_2= value2 or column_3= value3).
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
query.and(
                query.or(
                        query.criteria(field1).equal(value1),
                        query.criteria(field1).equal(null)
                ),
                query.or(
                        query.criteria(field2).equal(value2),
                        query.criteria(field3).equal(value3)
                )
            );
```

Also, below is the Mongodb query for the above

```
   db.FILE_JOURNEY.find(  {$and :[ {
                                    $or: [ { SUBSCRIBERID: "225136298" }, { SUBSCRIBERID : null} ]
                                },      
                                {   
                                    $or: [ { BATCHID : "615060299" }, { FILENAME : "TR.NYHBE.834Q.D.212311980342.QHP.dat" } ]  
                                }
                              ] 
                        } 
                    )
```

What things can I try next?

Comment: Can you please post an example document that you were expecting to match this query?

Answer (score 0):

If you try something like this:

```
   query.and(
       query.or(
          query.criteria(field1).equal(value1),
          query.criteria(field1).doesNotExist()
       ),
       query.or(
          query.criteria(field2).equal(value2),
          query.criteria(field3).equal(value3)
      )
   );
```

MongoDB/Morphia doesn't save fields with null values - it just skips that field, so the query for field=NULL would never match hence the `doesNotExist`. Strange that it doesn't give an warning. Do you have disableValidation() enabled?

Comment: still it's not working...Is doesNotExist() performing the function of checking null?? No, I have not used disableValidation().Does it make any difference?

Comment: doesNotExist() will return false if the value is null in the database.  You'll have to check for both if it could be either.  You'd be ahead telling morphia not to store nulls so you could simply do the existence check.